# How can I apply a php tag within a bootstrap dropdown so everything is aligned?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

Specifically:

I have managed to apply the if/else statement into the drop-down no problem. However, when I go to use the drop-down on the website, the item created by the if/else statement in this case, log in or logout, is set to the left-hand side, whereas everything else above in the drop-down is centre aligned. I have tried applying style in the various ways I know, but I am new to PHP, so I don't know how to apply styling to this particular item.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Code below:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="pots.php">POTS</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="pans.php">PANS</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="bowls.php">BOWLS</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="cups.php">CUPS</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="mugs">MUGS</a>

  <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
      echo '<a href="includes/logout.inc.php">LOGOUT</a>';
    } else {
      echo '<a href="login.php">LOGIN</a>';
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps you forgot to pass: `class="dropdown-item"` like this: `echo '<a href="login.php" class="dropdown-item">LOGIN</a>' ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The class missing should be the issue

```html
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="pots.php">POTS</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="pans.php">PANS</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="bowls.php">BOWLS</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="cups.php">CUPS</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="mugs">MUGS</a>
    
      <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
          echo '<a class="dropdown-item" href="includes/logout.inc.php">LOGOUT</a>';
        } else {
          echo '<a class="dropdown-item" href="login.php">LOGIN</a>';
        }
      ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Amazing! Really couldn't wrap my head around where the class should go and I must have tried everywhere except there! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. I have done this for you now though! Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate!